# Sending scp password in a Swift Application

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift, scp

I am working on a Mac app that uses scp, but I'm stuck on the password portion of the scp login.

This is what I have so far:

```
    let argLine1 = "~/Desktop/fileName"
    let argLine2 = "user@someplace.com:~/"
    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/scp"
    task.arguments = [argLine1, argLine2]

    let pipe = NSPipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe

    task.launch()
```

This appears to be connecting but display the following error:

Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
lost connection

I'm guessing that I need to find a way to send the password along with the arguments?  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you redirect the input?